# How to get thread dump using kill -3 command?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, thread-dump

I am taking a thread dump using kill -3 pid...Also I had used the following jvm agrs in my jboss config, like -

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log
```

Technically this doesn't "redirect" the thread dump output. It turns on JVM logging into jvm.log (which includes thread dump output). But I want only thread dump output using this command...please can anybody help me on this, on how can I get thread dump using kill -3 command.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Java 6+ has `jmap` for that - or use jconsole along with the top threads plugin for that (that's what we do).

Comment: jmap is used for capturing heap dump not thread dump.

Comment: You're right, it's not `jmap` but `jstack`.

Comment: @thomas, I know about jstack as well, it can be used, but my requirement is to use kill -3.